# retrieve multiple rows form android sqlite

Tags: java, android, sqlite

I am going to fetch some rows with specific tag in android Sqlite. 
The problems are

1. I got 15 with `cursor.getCount();` but 13 rows retrieved.
2. the 13 rows just repeat last row data

here is my code

```
public ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> getTodo(String tag) {
    ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>> arList = new ArrayList<HashMap<String,String>>();
    HashMap<String, String> todo = new HashMap<String, String>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
                + COLUMN_TAG + " = ?";
    String[] args={tag};

    SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
    Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, args);
    // Move to first row
    cursor.moveToFirst();
    System.out.println(cursor.getCount());
    if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
        do {
            todo.put(COLUMN_ID, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID)));
            todo.put(COLUMN_FROM, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FROM)));
            todo.put(COLUMN_TO, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TO)));
            todo.put(COLUMN_TITLE, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TITLE)));
            todo.put(COLUMN_TAG, cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TAG)));

            arList.add(todo);
        } while (cursor.moveToNext());
    }
    cursor.close();
    db.close();
    // return todo
    return arList;
}
```

Please help. Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using the *same* `todo` object for all rows, so you end up with lots of references to the same object.

Create a new one for each row in the loop:

```
Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, args);
try {
    while (cursor.moveToNext()) {
        HashMap<String, String> todo = new HashMap<String, String>();
        todo.put(...);
        ...
        arList.add(todo);
    }
finally {
    cursor.close();
}
```

Answer (score 2):

It's better to make the todo's you want to acquire into objects

```
public class Todo {
    public String id, from, to, title, tag;

    //setters and getters (not necessary)
}

public ArrayList<MyData> getTodo(String tag) {
    ArrayList<MyData> arList = new ArrayList<MyData>();
    String selectQuery = "SELECT * FROM " + TABLE_NAME + " WHERE "
            + COLUMN_TAG + " = ?";
    String[] args={tag};


    try {
        SQLiteDatabase db = this.getReadableDatabase();
        Cursor cursor = db.rawQuery(selectQuery, args);
        // Move to first row
        if (!cursor.moveToFirst())
            return arList;
        do {
            Todo todo = new Todo();
            todo.id = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_ID));
            todo.from = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_FROM));
            todo.to = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TO));
            todo.title = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TITLE))
            todo.tag = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(COLUMN_TAG));
            arList.add(todo);
        }  while(cursor.moveToNext());
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
        return arList;
    }
    finally {
        cursor.close();
        db.close();
    }
}
```

You keep putting new strings to an already created hashmap, but you keep using the same keys, and therefore, many entries get replaced. The `Todo` object keeps your code readable. You should also check if the cursor can jump to the first entry (which makes a getCount call unnecessary)